# How do you reload a tableView in ios6 with a mutable array?

Tags: uitableview, ios6, nsmutablearray

I have a tableview set up with data from a mutable array but I cannot figure out how to reload it, or even if it's being loaded in the first place.

The mutable array is changed when a user presses a button. When I initialize the array with test data, the table view works fine. I figured that I needed to reload the table, but I've been unsuccessful doing it inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. I've also tried to reload by synthesizing the tableView through the .h and reloading after adding to the array from the add button being clicked method (attempts not reflected in code, but if you think I did it wrong go ahead and post the right way).

There is no error, but nothing happens when I click the add button.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Relevant code:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *company;
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender;


**@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *currentNames;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *currentCompanies;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *names;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *companies;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *preExisting;**
@end
```

.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

**@synthesize name, company, currentNames, currentCompanies, names, companies;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSMutableArray *currentNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *currentCompanies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *companies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.preExisting = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];**
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    this.tableView = tableView;
    return [currentNames count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [currentNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView reloadData];
}


- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    BOOL exists = [names containsObject:name.text];

    if(exists == FALSE){
        [currentNames addObject:[name text]];
        [currentCompanies addObject:[company text]];
        [names addObject:[name text]];
        [companies addObject:[company text]];
    }
    else{
        [currentNames addObject:[name text]];
        [currentCompanies addObject:[company text]];
    }

    [currentNames addObject:[name text]];
    **[_preExisting reloadData];**

    name.text=@"";
    company.text=@"";

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

`TableView` uses data source (`NSArray`s or `NSMutableArray`s) to populate itself. It uses various delegate methods to know how its going to be populated. So in your case, you are using your `currentNames`, an instance of `NSMutableArray` to do so. When you manipulate the data inside this array, you would want the `TableView` to show the now edited array.

So to reload your table view after you are done editing the array in your button's action method, you should call this method

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

there.

**Note** :- You would want your data source array to have a scope till your view controller lasts so if you have created a `NSMutableArray` property in your `Interface` file, do not recreate an instance of `NSMutableArray` of the same name in your `Implementation` file (do not ignore compiler warnings).

In your `viewDidLoad` method, use

```
self.currentNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Although it will create a memory leak by the way but seriously, go through `TableView`'s [documentation](http://goo.gl/chczu) thoroughly before you move ahead.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried the reload in my add action method, but hopefully with these initialize fixes it should work. I'll get back to you after reading through more of the docs and trying it!

Comment: Hey, I've made some changes and I believe I'm very close, but the table view will not load in new data still. Do you have any other suggestions? I updated the changes to the main post surrounded by **

Comment: @NetworkIntern Do you get the updated `currentNames` before you reload data in your table view in `add:` method. NSLog the array there before you reload your data and I think you will see that your array is not updated thats why table view does not show the updated data.

Comment: Also, in your `viewDidLoad` method, do not redeclare variables as your property names. Instead of doing `NSMutableArray *currentNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` , just do this `currentNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` for all your arrays and if you have created tableview instance in Interface Builder and connected it properly, there is no need to alloc init it in `viewDidLoad`, remove that line from there.